# self signed vs CA signed certificate

Tags: certificates

I am trying to update an expiring self signed certificate in salesforce.
I want to know what is the difference between self signed and CA signed certificates and when to use either of them.

I know that self signed is easy and CA requires some time to get it done. Can you please clarify the differences and use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Self-signed certificates are for applications with no public domain name that cannot be accessed outside a local or VPN network. CA certificates should be used for applications with a public domain name and must be secured.

For example, your SSO solution using AD FS most likely used a self-signed certificate. Your public web portal with a public SSO feature would need a CA certificate.

The difference lies in "trust." Internal applications are not trusted on the Internet globally, while external applications must be. Most software is configured to only accept CA certificates while on the Internet, but will allow self-signed certificates for internal networks.